# Ansible, pg_hba.conf configuration with IPs from hosts file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have problem and i don't did i even start correctly.

i have hosts file that looks like

```
all:
  children:
    application1:
      children:
        application1-webserver:
          hosts:
            host1.domain.net:
            host2.domain.net:
        application1-database:
          hosts:
            dbhost1.domain.net:
    application2:
      children:
        application2-webserver:
          hosts:
            host3.domain.net:
            host4.domain.net:
        application1-database:
          hosts:
            dbhost2.domain.net:
    app-servers:
      hosts:
            host1.domain.net:
            host2.domain.net:
            host3.domain.net:
            host4.domain.net:
```

I have created template file. I know it is not pg_hba.conf, but it is no mater now, if i get IPs out it will be easy

```
{% for i in groups['app-servers'] %}
{{ hostvars[i]['ansible_default_ipv4_address'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

So maybe for time to time i have to run this script to create "new" enviroment, and i don't want to change IPs from app-servers manually. What i want is to get IP from FQDN.

Need this so i can limit access to db from network, just to those servers.

Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Are you getting an error when you try to use that template? At first glance it looks okay.

Comment: Yes i'm getting error fatal: 

`FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4_address'"}`

Running this against one test server i have. I have network access to all servers

Answer (score 0):

The variable holding the global info is `ansible_default_ipv4`. It is only available if you have gathered facts on your host (make sure you did not use `gather_facts: false` on your play).

It's a hash containing several keys among which `address`. As an example (obfuscated), this is what I get on my localhost:

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a gather_subset=network -a filter=*default_ipv4*
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_default_ipv4": {
            "address": "x.y.z.a",
            "alias": "interface",
            "broadcast": "x.y.z.255",
            "gateway": "x.y.z..1",
            "interface": "interface",
            "macaddress": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
            "mtu": 1500,
            "netmask": "255.255.255.0",
            "network": "x.y.z..0",
            "type": "ether"
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

So the name of the var you are looking for in your template is `ansible_default_ip4.address`

Your full fixed template:

```
{% for i in groups['app-servers'] %}
{{ hostvars[i].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

Possible alternative notations (mixing dot and array notation):

```
{{ hostvars[i]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}
{{ hostvars[i].ansible_default_ipv4['address'] }}
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

So i got it. It is little complicated.

Playbook looks like this:

```
---
- hosts: app-servers
  tasks:
    - ping:

- hosts: dbhost1.domain.net
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: test-for
...
```

Hosts file like above:

```
all:
  children:
    application1:
      children:
        application1-webserver:
          hosts:
            host1.domain.net:
            host2.domain.net:
        application1-database:
          hosts:
            dbhost1.domain.net:
    application2:
      children:
        application2-webserver:
          hosts:
            host3.domain.net:
            host4.domain.net:
        application1-database:
          hosts:
            dbhost2.domain.net:
    app-servers:
      hosts:
            host1.domain.net:
            host2.domain.net:
            host3.domain.net:
            host4.domain.net:
```

Only after i ping hosts i get IPs i need

Then in template:

```
{% for i in groups['app-servers'] %}
{{ hostvars[i].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

And it works.

Thanks